# Xamarin: Xamarin Google Map always shows the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps instead of loading map

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have used Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps in my app for google map. But it always shows **Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps** message instead of loading google map as shown in below image.

In Android: Manifest file i added all permissions and key. I initiated in main activity file.

[I am getting this Message instead of loading map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sstGw.png)

Am I missing something?

Android manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.eShop.Mobile" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="eShop.Mobile.Android">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="*********" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**View.Xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <!-- Place new controls here -->
            <maps:Map VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            </maps:Map>
            <!--<Label Text="check"></Label>-->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**MAinActivity.cs**

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TryToLocationGetPermissions();
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

Comment: someone will able to help you if you share code or repro project

Comment: Is Google play services is installed in your emulator, if not check on any physical android device it will work

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi In physical device also its not working.

Comment: Make sure that the API key that you have entered is correct, Also make sure you are following all the steps mentioned here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map

Comment: Try this `android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"` instead of android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"

Comment: This problem is solved now. If someone face such issue in future can do the follwing: if targetAndroid version is 8.1 oreo it will work But if its pie 9: U need to install from nuget package Googleplayservices.map And in Androidmanifest file Add : <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />. These things solved my issue